# How to fadein and fadeout in single UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiview

example
i try to change cell.accessoryView from picture1 to picture2 by fadein

but my problem is i only have one accessoryView(one UIView)

any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a fade, you'll have to modify your accessory view rather than reset `cell.accessoryView`.  The simplest approach may be to give your accessory two subviews, one each for picture1 and picture2.

```
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
UIImageView *imageView2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
imageView2.alpha = 0;
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:imageView1];
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:imageView2];
```

Then do the following to fade between:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
imageView1.alpha = 0;
imageView2.alpha = 1;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 6):

if i understood your question properly...

you can try something like

```
    //-------fade out

- (void)animateFadingOut{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animateFadingIn)];

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

//set transformation
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:NewImgeView];
cell.accessoryView.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
-(void)animateFadingIn{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

//set transformation
cell.accessoryView.alpha = 1.0;

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: thnaks mihirpmehta let's me try